# Gzip on js/css files on Django

Tags: javascript, django, gzip

I know that it's better to use something like AWS for static files but I am on developing stage and I prefer to have javascript/css files on localhost.

It would be great if I could get gzip working on my javascript files for testing. I am using the default gzip middleware but it's just compressing the view request.

My template looks like:

```
<script src='file.js' type='application/javascript'></script>
```

There should be a type-of-file list similar to Nginx for the django-based-server. How can I add application/javascript, text/javascript, etc for gzip compression?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576449/django-how-can-i-gzip-staticfiles-served-in-dev-mode

Comment: Thank you @RetoAebersold! I did that and it's working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the [GZipMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.gzip) documentation, where it's explained that the middleware will not compress responses when the "Content-Type header contains javascript or starts with anything other than text/".

EDIT:

To clarify what the documentation says, if the `Content-Type` header value contains `javascript` or doesn't begin with `text/`, then the response won't be compressed. That means both `text/javascript` and `application/javascript` will be invalid responses, since they match `javascript`.

Those restrictions are intentionally imposed by the middleware itself, but you can still circumvent that by wrapping the static files view handler with the `gzip_page()` decorator and adding it to your URL configuration manually.

Comment: @frank I've updated the answer with some clarification of what the docs say and how you can circumvent the response compression restriction with the suggested solution form the docs.

Comment: Thank you. I followed these instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576449/django-how-can-i-gzip-staticfiles-served-in-dev-mode

Answer (score 0):

During development you are using the Django built-in webserver, this server is really simple and does not have any other options than what you can see with `./manage.py help runserver`

You options are either to setup a real webserver or use the `staticfiles` app with a custom `StaticFilesStorage`

But honestly, this is overkill, why would want to test gzip compression?

Comment: I need to download large files in a few seconds.

Comment: may be what you can do then is bypass any webserver altogether and tell the browser to access your static files directly by setting the STATIC_URL to point to your static folder through the filesystem, this is the faster you can get.